The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permissionError- iphone - Audio
Hi in my react application I have audio player from React Audio Player to play audio.Audio is playing fine for chrome ,safari , mac but in iphone( chrome & safari ) it throws the error a below:
"unhandled Promise Rejection : NotAllowedError : The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied"
Bqasically it is a chat application and I will get the audioURL from the server and once it is reached I will update the URL and when it is update I will play it as below code :
The component ( ChatMessage.tsx ):
import ReactAudioPlayer from 'react-audio-player';

.
.
.

  const [audioURL, setAudioURL] = useState<string>('');
  const audioPlaybackRateRef = useRef<number>(1);


  useEffect(() => {
    if (audioPlayerRef.current && audioPlayerRef.current.audioEl.current) {
      audioPlayerRef.current.audioEl.current.play();
      audioPlayerRef.current.audioEl.current.playbackRate =
        audioPlaybackRateRef.current;
    }
  }, [audioURL]);

  const handleSpeak = (conversationId: string, msgID: number) => {
    setIsAudioLoading(true);
    setHasPreviousAudio(true);
    updateAudioPlaybackSpeed();
    getAudioUrl(conversationId, msgID)
      .then((response) => {
        setAudioURL(response.data.audio_url);
        setIsAudioPlaying(true);
        setIsAudioPlayingForCall(true);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setTTSError(true);
        setAudioURL('');
        notifyError(error);
        setIsStreaming(false);
        setHasPreviousAudio(false);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setIsAudioLoading(false);
      });
  };

.
.
.
      <ReactAudioPlayer
        src={audioURL}
        controls={false}
        ref={audioPlayerRef}
        onEnded={onAudioCompletion}
      />



Many developers suggest to have muted true but I have to play the audio so I cannot mute it.
When I try to debug in iphone ( chrome & safari ) it tells the error in the line number :
audioPlayerRef.current.audioEl.current.play(); is there.
